# with LoadJobConfig() function load automatic schema without data type using python api

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a csv file in bigquery, but when I put the automatic schema it also tells me what type of data it is. Is there a possibility that it detects all the columns in String?
I am using this code

```
    cl = bigquery.Client()
    jc = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    jc.skip_leading_rows = 1
    jc.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    jc.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    jc.autodetect=True
```

I tried to use autodetect from LoadJobConfig() but it also does the data type.